# Unity/C# cannot find WriteableBitmap, BitmapSource, Int32Rect, and PixelFormat

Tags: c#

My project requires some image processing from the kinect camera and the BackgroundRemovalTool class I found uses [WriteableBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap(v=vs.110).aspx), [BitmapSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource(v=vs.110).aspx), [Int32Rect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.int32rect(v=vs.110).aspx), and [PixelFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat(v=vs.110).aspx). It says it cannot find them, despite me trying to declare the namespace. Eg:

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows;
```

But this doesn't work. I also read I should get the DLL files (eg. PresentationCore.dll) but Unity just ignores them. It provides no error message. I use the .NET Framework v3.5 folder when copying them from program files. Am I going in the wrong direction here? How do I use these variable types and enums?

Comment: Unity doesn't have those types.

Comment: Where/how did you *"get the DLL files"* into Unity? Also note that Unity uses a mono version that is equivalent to .NET 2.0 so your DLLs may not work. (And finally please remove the "unityscript" tag, that is something else)

Comment: I searched my computer and found ones in a low version. I read that Unity using .NET couldn't read anything past 3.5. So I used those versions. I don't know where that number came from, and maybe that's not the version of Unity I'm using.

Comment: I don't have any that are listed in the .Net framework listed as v 2.0.